# How to install Python on Windows 10

Tags: python

I have uninstalled Python and now I cant install it anymore (error 0x800705b4). Has anybody encountered this error ? I have tried different versions but nothing works.

Comment: where are you getting this error ?

Comment: I get this error after I try to launch the setup installer as an admin - I get to the Setup Progress window, then after a while it returns the following message: 0x800705b4 - operation ended because the delay period has expired

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error after a little digging I found the below thing...It works like a charm...
First...Make sure to check the setup package for your system which is X86 or x64, download packages based on the system before you proceed, otherwise, the hack won't work. The below is explained for x64 bit windows 8.1 system with a 64 bit Python setup package use the below-mentioned setup name(.exe file) in Step1: and search in google for downloading the Python setup

Start CMD as Admin, after that

**Step1**: ~`YourFilePath/python-3.5.0-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0`

**Step2**:

```
~YourFilePath/python-3.5.0-amd64.exe
```

~YourFilePath stands for the location of the `python-3.5.0-amd64.exe` file on your PC Example: `E:\Softwares\python-3.5.0-amd64.exe`

now after executing Step2: the setup will run without any errors..... Cool...

The above-mentioned steps should work or else If you find any difficulties please visit [here](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using/windows.html) which explains the process in detail. Good Luck...

Credits to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/978077/1091110)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html) for Windows which has seperate environments.

The solution I would recommend though is to use [**WinPython**](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), which after install is just a folder with everything you need, doesn't change a thing in your windows environment and still works great! There is also a version that comes with the most used packages already installed, give it a try!

No need to mess with environments, just use a different WinPython folder for your projects!

Answer (score -1):

Eventually what did the trick for me was to roll back the previous microsoft update (KB4512575)