I have a problem running python code in vs terminal

Unable to find python module. it prints that multiple times
I tried to download the same version of my vs python which is 3.11.7 in my terminal by using the command pip install python 3.11.7 but it gives me errors.
What should I do?

Try this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/77373604/2296458

Um, if you don't have python, you can't use python (pip) to install python. Install it with chocolatey or download the windows installer from the website and follow the instructions.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101490/how-to-install-python-on-windows-10

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

"your vs" doesn't has a python version, python is installed on the system. You can have multiple version of python on the same system at once and create virtual environments to work with.
But apparently vs code did find a valid python installation,so if when you type "python" it doesn't execute python then you probably need to add it to your windows environment vars.
If this doesn't work, make sure to uninstall all python files from your computer, download the last version from python official website and install following the installer steps, at one point it'll ask if you want to add it to path automatically and then you can start working right away.

when I want to use control + shift + p  i still get this error
2024-05-04 14:23:19.125 [error] Error while running venv creation script:  CREATE_VENV.DOWNLOAD_PIP_FAILED
2024-05-04 14:23:19.126 [error] CREATE_VENV.DOWNLOAD_PIP_FAILED

it's a problem with "pip", python package manager, do a  py -m ensurepip --upgrade in your terminal, if this doesn't work you can try py get-pip.py
